# Updating a specific item in a shopping list csv using php

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

As you can see I have a majority of the step done. My goal is to create a basic shopping list using 0 for not checked off, and 1 for checked off. If a user inputs the name of the list and the item they wish check off the list the 0 will be replaced by a 1. I know I have to loop over each row in the csv and then edit the item the user inputs in the terminal. However I think I did something slightly wrong in the while loop and need help on where to fix.  Here is my code:

```
<?php

$args = $argv;

if(!isset($args[2])) {
    echo 'Not given a shopping list title or item to edit!' . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
$listName = $args[1];

$fileName = $listName . '.csv';
$path = __DIR__ . '/../storage/' . $fileName;

$resource = fopen($path, 'a+');

$item = $args[2];

$rows = [];
while(($row = fgetcsv($resource)) !== false) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    if($rows === $item) {
        $item[1] = 1;
    }
    while($rows == 0) {
        fputcsv($resource, $rows);
    }
}

fclose($resource);
```

Here is my csv:

```
bananas,0
apples,0
lettuce,0
potatoes,0
pasta,0
rice,0
tofu,0
tempeh,0
berries,0
```

For example if the user wishes to check off rice the 0 will be replaced with a 1.

Edit: The code works up until if($rows === $item) statement. What I am doing with while(($row=fgetcsv($resource)) !== false) { $rows[] = $row; } is get each row of the csv in one array because when I ran the code I only got the first line of the code. And then I add it to the empty rows array to make each entry (there are 9 of them to be in the same array. So when a user wishes to check an item off the list each item will be in the same array and easier to refer to.

This part

```
 if($rows === $item) {
        $item[1] = 1;
    }
    while($rows == 0) {
        fputcsv($resource, $rows);
    }
```

I am unsure about because I want to target the 1st index point of whatever item the user types in and wants to check off.

Comment: Just use a database - so much simpler to do this kind of task with an UPDATE query.

Comment: The assignment was to use a CSV file first since I just have 1 with 9 entries, and then eventually I will be shifting it all over to a database.

Comment: What's the point of `$rows[] = $row;` supposed to be? Why would you need all rows collected in an array here to begin with? And then on the next line, you are comparing that with `$rows === $item`, type-safe, which probably makes even less sense. And how is `while($rows == 0)` supposed to ever terminate, when you do nothing that could change $rows in any way inside the loop?

Comment: Ok. So please explain to us what the specific problem is. "something wrong" doesn't describe what issue you're having when you run the code, or what you've done to [try and debug it](http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/) so far. Be more precise, and give an example of the input you provided, the expected output, and the actual output. You can [edit] your question to add the explanation. CBroe has hit on some likely snags already, though.

Comment: Edited it! Hope it helps with where I am coming from.

Comment: Might want to do some basic error checking. People easily typo. Therefore, check for the existence of the file as well and give error message and exit if not found.

Comment: `$rows === $item` can never be true because `$rows` is an array, and `$item` is (presumably) a string containing some text. Did you mean to test a specific value _within_ `$rows`, perhaps?

Comment: Yes an item within the row!

Comment: Well `$rows` is potentially a collection of _all_ your rows, so that makes even less sense. Maybe you meant `$row[0] === $item` then

Comment: N.B. `$rows == 0` also makes no sense, for the same reason. Were you trying to count the number of rows, perhaps? Not really clear what this bit of code is for.

Comment: Oh 0 is for when an item is on the list and not checked off. So automatically when a user inputs an item to the list it puts 0, but I want to change it to 1, if the user puts the specific item in the row in the terminal.

Comment: Right so that means you'd need `$row[1] == 0` because that value is in the second part of your row. `$row` itself is an array. Use `var_dump($row);` if you're not sure what it contains. I think maybe you need a tutorial on working with PHP arrays, because you seem to be a bit at sea with the basic concepts.

Comment: Basically looks like that you have the fputcsv within another loop. I believe your intension is 1) read in a row; 2) check for the item you want to update and updating when found (within $row, not $item); 3) put the row.

Comment: `fputcsv($resource, $rows);` isn't going to change the data the way you want though either. You'd need to first update the row - e.g. `$row[1] = 1;` and then pass that to fputcsv. Unclear if you're wanting it to remove the existing entry as well? Otherwise you'll have two of the same. Not sure why they set you the assignment of using a CSV for this _first_, because it's way more fiddly than using a database.

Comment: Thanks...it's been a really rough day and my head isn't in it today. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can warmly suggest [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) as a technique to follow when you're confused by what your code is doing. It forces you to go through the code line by line and validate to yourself what it's for and why it's there and what you think it does (which you can also check by reading documentation and testing the line/function in isolation). http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/basic-debugging/ also has a simple guide to general basic debugging with PHP. Also make sure you've switched on PHP's full error reporting so you can see all warnings etc.